# gdb reading assembly x86 instructions in wrong order

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

I am using command

```
yasm -f elf64 -g dwarf2 example.asm
```

to assemble my code and

```
ld -g -o example example.o
```

to link it. Then I'm debugging my code with ddd debugger, which is just a front end for gdb. The same thing happens using gdb.

This is the code I wrote

```
section .data

EXIT_SUCCESS equ 0
SYS_exit equ 60

section .text
global _start
_start:

mov rax, 0

for:
inc rax
cmp rax, 10
jne for


last:
mov rax, SYS_exit
mov rdi, EXIT_SUCCESS
syscall
```

When i use ddd or gdb, set breakpoint just before the start of the program and use "step" a multiple times, the green arrow (signifying next instruction) just jumps back and forth between line

```
mov rax, 0
```

and line

```
inc rax
```

This is not what I expected to happen because there is nowhere in the code where I return to the "mov rax, 0" command, so I don't see how could it be the next instruction after the beginning.

Weirdly enough, if I add one completely redundant (I think) instruction "mov r8, 0" at the beginning, so the code looks like this

```
section .data

EXIT_SUCCESS equ 0
SYS_exit equ 60

section .text
global _start
_start:

mov rax, 0
mov r8, 0

for:
inc rax
cmp rax, 10
jne for


last:
mov rax, SYS_exit
mov rdi, EXIT_SUCCESS
syscall
```

The code works just as I would expect, the green arrow moving inside the for loop.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Sounds like YASM is making broken debug info, or else DDD has a problem.  Did you try NASM?  Or more importantly, did you try disassembly mode?  I never use source view when debugging asm, just disassembly view (`layout reg` in plain GDB in a terminal window, even though that's kind of clunky it's good enough that I haven't bothered looking much for a better GUI).

Comment: Could be some sort of off-by-one error.

Comment: @PeterCordes I tried to assemble with nasm, and I think it uses different debug info. The code assembled with nasm and linked with ld when I use "step" in ddd or gdb finishes in three steps, goes through for in just one step. I typed layout reg in gdb and it returned  "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'gdb_exception_RETURN_MASK_ERROR'".

Comment: @fuz could you expand? How could I fix this error?

Comment: Use `stepi` (short form `si`) to step by instructions so source lines don't matter for stepping, only for the debugger showing the current position in the source.

Comment: Did you use `layout reg` inside the GDB command window in DDD, or in stand-alone `gdb` in a terminal window?  For me GDB only crashes when the program being debugged exits.  (So `layout reg` is probably pretty buggy, but at least its usable for one run of the program.  I have GDB 9.1 on Arch Linux.  It was similar with GDB 8.x before.)

Comment: @Don'tDownVote  I don't think you can fix this error.  As Peter Cordes said, it's likely incorrectly generated debug information.  As a quick band-aid, simply remember that the instruction actually being executed is the one after what the debugger says.

Comment: @fuz how do I know when this happens? In the second code for some reason it works, In the first one it works for a few instructions and then in doesn't. How do I identify when it does work, and when it does not?

Comment: @Don'tDownVote I don't know.  By the way, have you edited your code between assembling and debugging it?  That's a common source for this sort of problem as adding new lines shifts all lines below the new line downwards.

Comment: @fuz No, every time after editing the code I reassemble and re-link the program.